# admin edit link from a specific page

Tags: admin

When I am not logged in my WordPress site, suppose I am in a page like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/wordpress/pagename
```

Is there any way that I can create a direct link to the edit admin page for this specific 'pagename'? For example, something like

```
http://www.mysite.com/wordpress/pagename/wp-edit
```

which of course will require first admin login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I completely follow your second example.

You can use [`get_edit_post_link()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_edit_post_link/) template tag, which will output the link to admin side for the current post (only for users who *can* edit the post).

If you just want *pretty* link for that there is no native way, but it looks similar to what [Slash Edit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/slash-edit/) plugin does.

Comment: Slash Edit is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!!!